# CKeditor used on form input

Tags: content-management-system, ckeditor

Is it possible to use ckeditor on a form input instead of textarea, i am building a CMS and now trying to add ckeditor and majority of of fields are form input not textarea

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use CKEditor on an element (a div, say) that has contenteditable set. In fact, by default contenteditable elements will have CKEditor editors instantiated. It seems unconventional to use a rich text editor on an input of type text but I imagine it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know CkEditor has to be created using a textarea.  In saying this, I am using it in a Razor MVC view and its one of the classes in my form..

The request will be blocked though and you will get this error;

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client

To get around this, you need to get the value of the CKEditor text and html encode it.  You can do this

when submitting your form, intercept it on the onsubmit function:

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="javascript:onFormSubmit(this);return false" >
...
</form>
```

Then in this onFormSubmit function

1. Get the value,
2. Set the property value to the url encoded value
3. Do a ajax call to your server with the data

Your function will get the CKEditor encoded value like so:

```
    function onFormSubmit(form)
    {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances["EditorId"];
        var richtextValue = editor.getData();
        var urlEncodedValue =  encodeURIComponent(richtextValue);

       // TODO rest of code doing ajax post to submit your form and its data

       // Here you need to do an ajax call to your server pass it the form data along with the url encoded CKEditor value for that property

    }
```